# differentiable equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function, continuous on $[a,b]$. Prove that $\forall \alpha >0,$ there exist $c_{1},c_{2}\in (a,b)$ so that $f'(c_{1})+\alpha f'(c_{2})=0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $f(x) = x$, then $f' = 1$ and this would not hold